# pass my cart <div> tag from one jsp to next jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets, shopping-cart

I had developed a shopping cart in the right div tag of the page and on left side we have displayed the items user can add to the cart,
it works perfectly fine

but now the problem arises at final checkout page where we want to pass cart to next jsp page where user can choose mode for payment..

How to pass full div tag to next Jsp page?
please help..

Comment: you don't pass full DIV to next page, you pass some thing that will make it able to regenerate full DIV on next page

Comment: what do you mean by full div tag. do you mean that you want to show the cart items on next page

Comment: yes, i want to show cart items on next page..

Comment: Why dont you put the parameter in a form and forward to other jsp and get the parameters there

Comment: thanks everybody for showing me the ways..
i just needed to pass some variables to retrieve that data on next page.. :)